# How to convert Blob to File in Electron

Tags: javascript, typescript, file, electron

Does anyone know how to convert `Blob` to `File` object in ElectronJS. I tried:

```
return new File([blob], fileName, {lastModified: new Date().getTime(), type: blob.type});
```

but it seems that ElectronJs has different API of File object:

ElectronJs File function:

[image]

Chrome Browser File function

[image]

I also tried:

```
(blob as any).name = fileName;
(blob as any).lastModified = new Date().getTime();
return blob as File;
```

but doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

I found workourd:

```
blobToFile(blob: Blob, filename: string) {
    const fd = new FormData();
    fd.set('foo', blob, filename);
    return fd.get('foo') as File;
}
```